# Convert timestamp to hours and minutes for a movies' length

Tags: php, timestamp

I have converted the length of the movie Avatar from 2009, from minutes to timestamp. The movie is 162 minutes long so the timestamp is 1386227800. Now I need to convert the timestamp to hours and minutes which I don't know how.

In short: how can I convert a timestamp and get the **correct** result in hours and minutes?

I have tested `floor(1386227800 / 60)`, `date('H:i', mktime(0, 1386227800)` and some functions that converts a timestamp to hours and minutes, but these only converts the hours to something endless, like `12375` or something like that.

So, how can I accomplish this?

Comment: `I have converted the length of the movie Avatar from 2009, from minutes to timestamp.` -- it makes no sense. Timestamps represent point in time, not duration

Comment: Ok. So the timestamp I got from `strtotime(162)` is not correct?

Comment: A timestamp doesn't represent an arbitrary duration.  It is the number of seconds elapsed since Jan 1 1970, so 162 minutes isn't meaningful (unless you mean to represent Jan 1 1970 at 02:42

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yea. I am aware of that. So my timestamp is not correct? If the answer is no, then I have to stick with the minutes and not convert them to a timestamp :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As one of the commenters mentioned, a timestamp represents a single point in time, not a duration. There's no reason to call strtotime at all -- if you already have the total minutes, you can ignore converting it to a timestamp and just get that into hours:minutes like this:

```
$time=162;

$hours = floor($time / 60);
$minutes = ($time % 60);

echo $hours.":".$minutes;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
echo date('H:i:s', 1386227800);
```

Comment: That prints `08:16:40`

Comment: That's incorrect answer, because date() includes time zone... Example, you want print echo date('H:i:s', 100); // The answer in  my country 1:01:40 :))

Answer (score 1):

Can you try,

```
 echo date('H:i','1386227800');
```

Comment: That's incorrect answer, because date() includes time zone... Example, you want print echo date('H:i:s', 100); // The answer in my country 1:01:40 :))

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to convert 162 minutes to be represented with hours and minutes. This is a simple case of mathematics.

```
<?php

$minutes = 162 % 60;
$hours = floor(162 / 60);

?>
```

`$hours` will return 2, and `$minutes` will return 42. 2 hours, 42 minutes is equivalent to 162 minutes.

Hope this helps.