# Split Strtotime('now') to seconds and minutes

Tags: php

I am developing a browser game where the player gets hospitalized for 30 minutes when his health becomes 0. I am using strtotime to check how much time is left until he gets out of the hospital.

```html
<?php
$current_time = strtotime('now') + 1800; // This variable goes to the database
// The player gets hospitalized for 30 minutes, that's 1800 seconds.

// Updating the database ...
$sql = "UPDATE playerstats SET hospitalized='1', hospitaltimer=$current_time WHERE id = $id";
?>
```

Now let's say the player is in the page where it says he has to wait ?? minutes ?? seconds until he gets out of the hospital.

```html
<?php
// Getting the timer from the database ...
global $db;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM playerstats WHERE id=$id";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();

$timer = $result[0]['hospitaltimer'];
// substracting strtotime('now') from the timer to see how many seconds are left
// until the player is released from the hospital

$timer = $timer - strtotime('now');
// Lets just say that 2 minutes have passed, the $timer should now be with a result 
// like 1680 or something, 

?>
```

My question is, how to split that timer to minutes and seconds? I want to split the 1680 seconds that remain to minutes and seconds. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert timestamp to hours and minutes for a movies' length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20391749/convert-timestamp-to-hours-and-minutes-for-a-movies-length)

Comment: Off topic, depending on where `$id` comes from, you could be opening your app to SQL injection.

Comment: It's the session ID. The ID of my account.

Comment: Btw i saw what you linked but... hours and minutes... i need minutes and seconds. I can't wrap my head how i can get the seconds value.

Comment: Math. `$seconds = $duration % 60; $minutes = ($duration - $seconds) / 60;`

Comment: I got it i got it ... thanks for the help. GOSH im so retarded, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're storing `hospitaltimer` as seconds from the unix epoch, substracting both `strtotime` figures would then be converted to a date that's, for example, 1680 seconds after the unix epoch. Not what you're looking for.

I'd suggest approaching this by storing the "exit time" in yyyy-mm-dd format

a.- You'd need to alter your table and convert `hospitaltimer` to a `DATETIME` field. that's pretty straight-forward
b.- change your code to store the `hospitaltimer` value as a yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss like this:

`$current_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now') + 1800); // This variable goes to the database`

and then change the logic to show the remaining time:

```
$timer = date_create($result[0]['hospitaltimer']); // the "exit time" you inserted
$now = date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));

$diff = date_diff($timer,$now)->format('%r%i minutes %s seconds');

if ($diff < 0)
{
    echo "out";
}

else
{
    echo $diff." before being able to leave";
}
```

Alternatively, substracting the output of different `strtotime()` operations would be a non-standard way to calculate dates which you could work around by:

```
$timer = $timer - strtotime('now');
// now the timer reads 1680 per your example

$seconds = $timer % 60; // use modulo 60 to calculate seconds remaining after dividing seconds by 60 and retrieving the integer part of the result

$minutes = ($timer - $seconds) / 60; // from full timer, substract the seconds and the remaining amount, divided by 60 is converted to minutes
```

Both of these alternatives would work, but the benefit of storing the `hospitaltimer` as a timestamp is that at any given point you could easily query the table to find out how many users are still hospitalized (for example) by simply using a `where hospitaltimer > now()`

Comment: glad you did :)